# How can I unselect item in ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I have a ListView with a couple of items in it. When the ListView looses focus, the last selected ListViewItem is still "selected" with a gray background.
I would like to achieve that on ListView.FocusLost, the selection is gone and therefore the ListView.SelectedIndexChanged event will occur.
Any ideas?

I am using .NET CF 3.5.

Comment: Edited, now I got your sentence.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Suppose you are accessing the ListView from a parent form/control.

You can add this piece of code in the form's/control's constructor/load event:

```
this.myListView.LostFocus += (s, e) => this.myListView.SelectedIndices.Clear();
```

Ok, so in your case, you would replace that delegate with:

```
if (this.myListView.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
    for (int i = 0; i < this.myListView.SelectedIndices.Count; i++)
    {
        this.myListView.Items[this.myListView.SelectedIndices[i]].Selected = false;
    }
```

You can give the code a nicer form, btw.

Comment: SelectedIndices does not have a `Clear()` method, at least not in compact framework 3.5.

Comment: Your answer is pretty correct but your code will surely give 'IndexOutOfRange' or 'ArgumentOutOfRange' exception because the `this.myListView.SelectedIndices.Count` will be reduced by 1 in the first iteration itself...

Answer (score 21):

```
myListView.SelectedItems.Clear();
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is late but in case someone else needed the solution I would like to add to the solution.

You need to set the Focused property to false to avoid deselected items having focus.

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.myListView.SelectedIndices.Count; i++)
{
    this.myListView.Items[this.myListView.SelectedIndices[i]].Selected = false;
    this.myListView.Items[this.myListView.SelectedIndices[i]].Focused = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is easier.

```
this.myListView.SelectedIndex = -1;
this.myListView.Update();
```

Comment: there is no SelectedIndex property for listview

Comment: myListView.SelectedItem = null;

this works for my Xamarin Program, .Net Standard 2.0

Answer (score 2):

You can try it:

```
MyList.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => {
    ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
};
```

or if you have the OnSelection created in your View code behind(xaml.cs):

```
 private void OnSelection(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
        }
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Another effective way to approach this would be:

```
foreach (ListViewItem i in myListView.SelectedItems)
{
    i.Selected = false;
}
```

Comment: 'ListViewItem' does not contain a definition for 'Selected' and no extension method 'Selected' accepting a first argument of type 'ListViewItem' could be found

Comment: @Choletski I'm sure @Jeff ment `i.IsSelected = false;` instead of `i.Selected = false;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EditItemTemplate, rather than ItemTemplate, you may have been trying to figure out why ListView1.SelectedIndex = -1; hasn't been working. It's because you need to use ListView1.EditIndex = -1;

Answer (score -2):

```
if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
    {
        listView1.SelectedItems[i].Selected = false;
    }
```

Comment: The question was already answered 5 years ago. And your solution doesn't solve the problem - you're just unselecting the first item in the list.